# Slick slider effect

Tags: jquery, slick.js

I'm using Slick Slider jquery plugin.
http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

And I'm trying to create this effect : https://www.gillesetboissier.com/index.php?preload=1

To do that. I'm trying to keep the current slide in place to set translate3d to 0px. But this slider is blocked.

```
function slick_init() {
    $('.splash-slider').slick({
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: false,
        vertical: true,
        verticalSwiping: true
    });

    $('.splash-slider').on('beforeChange', function(event, currentSlide) {
        currentSlide.css('transform', 'translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)');
    });
}
```

What's wrong with this method please ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are trying to transform an element css from the arguments passed to the Slick `beforeChange` event, and in fact, the `currentSlide` parameter (in your implementation) is the reference to the slick instance. The one you are trying to use (the reference to the current slide — the third argument —) is the index of the current slide and not the reference to the slide itself.

`beforeChange` event takes 3 arguments:

- `slick`: the reference to the Slick instance
- `currentSlide`: the current slide, before the slide animation
- `nextSlide`: the next active slide after the slide animation

To get a slide by it index you could use the following snippet:

```
slider.find('[data-slick-index="'+slideIndex+'"]');
```

where `slider` is the instance of the Slick slider and `slideIndex` is the index of the slide you are trying to select.

So applying this to your code, you could do as follows:

```
$('.splash-slider').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide) {
    $('.splash-slider').find('[data-slick-index="'+currentSlide+'"]').css('transform', 'translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)');
});
```

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer. I understand better my mistake. So each time I want to have an action on a slide I must use the index. It works very well, but unfortunately I don't have the css effect that I'm searching. I will try to found a good effect in css.

Comment: @Jandon maybe if you point out what you want to achieve i could try to help you

Comment: Now you explained me well how it's work and I can manipulate the current slide before change. I'm trying to keep the current slide in the same position before change (no move for the current slide). So I thought that to put 0px on translate3D was the good solution, but it seems to be more complex. I'm tried too to put the current slide in absolute, top 0 but with no results. Something like that but with Slick : https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Fullscreen-Vertical-Slider-with-Parallax-Effect/

Comment: The problem is that who get transformed is the slide container and not each slide. Each slide is positioned using `float: left;` so if change how a slide is positioned it will affect all slides.

Comment: Ok so originally the structure of Slick Slider is not appropriate for the effect I'm searching for ? If each slides are positioned with `float: left` it will be more difficult. Typically this is a structure for horizontally slides with float. I was thinking that vertical option changed the operating process of Slick. In fact it's a sort of illusion.

Comment: @Jandon oh, i didn’t take that in to count. Never did a vertical slide with slick.